# Typescript function that accepts only functions returning the same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function `check(f)` of which parameter `f` is must be a function that returns the same type as its parameter, and the type will be inferred. For example:

```
check((v: number) => v + 1); // OK
check((s: string) => s.toLowerCase()); // OK
check((v: number) => v.toString()); // Not OK
```

I tried the following:

```
function check<T>(f: (v: T) => T) { }

check((v: number) => v > 10 ? v : ""); // Shouldn't be OK
```

The weird thing is, this code indeed reports error in the TypeScript [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawDwBUB8AFMAFyKEBuZuAlIgLz6K2IDeiAvgFBeoaaFKZMCAC2AIzQAnOo0QVETAIwAGRAH55iMgCIdNANxA) (which runs TypeScript 3.5.1), but it does not in my VS Code (which runs TypeScript 3.6.2), which infers the generic argument `T` as `<number | "">`. Does this happens because of some latest changes? If so, how can I still write the desired `check` function?

## Update

Here are the steps for reproducing the problem:

1. Create an empty folder.
2. Create file test.ts inside the folder, with its content being the sample code above. No other files are in the folder, so no tsconfig.json and thus all settings are default.
3. Open the folder with VS Code, and open test.ts. The editor shows no error with the code. Hovering the cursor above `check` function shows that it is inferred as `check<number | "">`.
4. Open the console and run `tsc test.ts`. Builds successfully with no error.

Comment: I don't think I get what you want. What is the return type of check suppose to be?

Comment: @JohnnyZabala `check` returns `void`. Don't worry about what `check` actually does, it is used mainly as type guard.

Comment: Well, you could set the generic type explicitly: `check<number>((v: number) => v > 10 ? v : ""));` and that should fail. But then, it should fail without it too....

Comment: @HereticMonkey The idea is that I want `check` to infer the type of `f` automatically. And yes, I agree that it should fail without explicitly assigning `T`, and I don't know why it does not.

Comment: I'm actually thinking it's doing the right thing; it's inferring the broadest possible type for `T`, since without guidance, it has to. It can't assume `number` just because you used it for `v`. But I'm going to let one of the TS experts that roam these virtual halls answer :).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on 3.6.2; it behaves the same for me as it does for 3.5.1 in the playground: `Argument of type '(v: number) => number | ""' is not assignable to parameter of type '(v: number) => number'.`  Looks like some other config issue is going on; please try to work on isolating a [mcve]; good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Please see my update for reproducing the error (or "no error", so to speak).

Comment: This may indeed be a Code error, but there is a logical argument for this behavior: `(string|number) => (string|number)` is a *subtype* of `string => string|number` (it is safe to substitute the former wherever you accept the latter), so it's arguably fair for the compiler to assume that this particular `check` call accepts `(string|number) => (string|number)` functions, even if the particular instance you passed is not that. if you do `check<number>` then this assumption cannot be enacted.

Comment: The TS Type compatibility page on function bivariance: "assignment succeeds if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter, or vice versa." If the compiler assumes `T = string|number`, the assignment is valid. I am not positive what the intended behavior is w.r.t. type inference, but providing the explicit type parameter fixes it. (Would still be curious to understand the cause of the discrepancy!)

Comment: @jagthebeetle May I ask which behavior are you experiencing in your case? Error or no error? Anyway, I do need the behavior as seen in the playground for my use case.

Comment: Yes, I reproduced what you are observing on VS code, but one way to "fix" it is just by doing `check<number>(/* your function */)`. looking at the bugs fixed for 3.6.2, I did see a few related to generic functions and overloads, so it's possible this behavior changed. (correction: jcalz' answer provides the config option that turns off function bivariance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not using the `--strict` compiler option; specifically you need to enable [the `--strictFunctionTypes` option](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) to start getting the error you expect.  It has nothing to do with version 3.5 vs 3.6 of TypeScript.  You (perhaps unintentionally) asked for parameter bivariance and that's what you got.

With `--strictFunctionTypes` off, then functions will unsafely be [bivariant in their parameter types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant), meaning you are allowed to *narrow* the type they accept.  It's safe to *widen* the type they accept (since every function that accepts a `number | ""` is also a function that accepts a `number`, you can give me the former if I expect the latter) but it is not safe to *narrow* it (since not every function that accepts a `number` is also a function that accepts a `number | ""`, you really shouldn't give me the former if I expect the latter).  Still, bivariance is *usefully* unsafe in some situations, so some form of it will probably stick around in TypeScript, at least for a while, and probably forever for backwards compatibility.

Unless you *want* parameter bivariance, you should turn on `--strictFunctionTypes`, and probably just `--strict`.  Hopefully that meets your needs.  Okay; hope that helps.  Good luck!